# I sent bitcoin and put low tx fee (4sat/b). Unconfirmed for 3 days. Can it be forever?

Tags: transactions, blockchain, transaction-fees, unconfirmed-transactions

I just want to withdraw bitcoin and put a low fee.
It's been 3 days and nothing happened with it - Unconfirmed.
So, can it be forever? Or how much time it may take to be confirmed? Or what should I do to make it faster?
I used a simple web blockchain wallet.
I've read about CPFP but I don't know how to find a private key in the blockchain wallet.
My tx: 347c25f1fb17fa0375f02268733910fe1ba1a94f28a61089fca754774c8cb0da

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is my transaction not getting confirmed and what can I do about it?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/9046/5406)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Fee rate used for the transaction: 4sat/vbyte and unconfirmed since 2 days 10 hours. Weird that I couldn't find the transaction using https://blockstream.info and had to use https://btc.bitaps.com
2. No it won't be unconfirmed forever
3. It should be confirmed in next couple of days looking at the mempool but you can't be sure. If enough users are willing to use a fee rate higher than 4 sat/vbyte, your transaction will not be prioritized by miners.
4. If you own one of the below addresses, you can try to spend unconfirmed transaction output and send BTC to one of your other address with a fee rate higher than others for a quick confirmation. Check https://mempool.observer to see fee rate of other unconfirmed transactions. This is called CPFP. Child transaction paying for parent transaction.

3GQdDSwSU5gJst9fvTH9fXz51aqUV3cb5W
1DdjvgaKTgpPXEQj5uhLxrkJqSEz2tk61Z

5. Use Electrum wallet: https://electrum.org/#download